# Find an injective map from $\{\frac{i}{2^n}:i\in\Bbb Z,n\in\Bbb N\}$ to $\Bbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Set: $A=\left\{\dfrac{i}{2^n} : i∈\Bbb Z, n∈\Bbb N\right\}$
Prove that A is countable by giving an example of an injective (one to one) map $f:A \to \Bbb N$

How do you find such an injective map?

Comment: "invective"? (in the title)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax. A basic [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Have you ever seen an example of an injection or bijection from $\Bbb N^2$ to $\Bbb N$?  Can you adapt one of those examples to work for your case?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** (*leading to one of the more common expected answers*)

Every integer can be written *uniquely* as a power of two times an odd number.

For example $25 = 2^0\times (25)$ and $12 = 2^2\times (3)$

---

**Further hint:**

Without loss of generality, any fraction we select from our set we may assume appears in simplest form.  That is to say, your set $A=\{\frac{i}{2^n}~:~i\in\Bbb Z,n\in\Bbb N\}$ we could have rewritten out of convenience as $A=\{\frac{i}{2^n}~:~i\in(2\Bbb Z+1),n\in\Bbb N\}$ where $i$ is allowed to range only over odd integers.

This allows us to avoid having to be overly careful about having $\frac{4}{2^9},\frac{2}{2^8}$ and $\frac{1}{2^7}$ all mapping to potentially different values despite being equal.